# Android Studio Gradle Sync Error "The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries"

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-api

I have updated all the firebase and google gms dependencies and still am getting this error, I don't know what's wrong?

Error-The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.1,11.0.1], [15.0.1,16.0.0), [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: May not be the cause of the error, but you should be using [firebase-ui:3.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases) for compatibility with the Firebase SDK and Support Lib versions you are using.

Comment: @BobSnyder Actually that fixed the error, thank you a lot, I was going crazy because of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [firebase-ui:3.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases) for compatibility with the Firebase SDK and Support Lib versions you are using